# Broken Surface Book Ppro after following tutorials.ubuntu steps

Tags: usb, data-recovery, surface

I followed the steps, got to [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0), then went to boot to Linux on my USB attached, there was a drive on there saying 'Install Ubuntu' and I figured that's how I might get some kind of persistent file storage, so I went for it. It looked like a reasonably simple interface giving me a slider on how much of the disk space on my USB Linux drive that I want to use so I used a little bit. The process crashed, and now my PC won't repair at all, as if I lost everything. Do you have any ideas? I'm considering taking it someone with a disk attachment compatible with my Surface Pro to find out what we can get out of it, if anything.